# Clear form fields on checkbox click

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a form, where the user fills in their details and can check, if the billing details are the same. In that case the same data gets copied to the billing section. The script for this works just fine.
However, in case the user clicks accidentally, the data should get deleted after clicking on the checkbox "billing info is different". I'm using a similar script, but instead of copying, I'm trying to add val(""). Could you please suggest, what I'm doing wrong?

Copy script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('input#choice_2_42_1').click(function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#input_2_35').val($('#input_2_9').val());
            $('#input_2_36').val($('#input_2_10').val());
            $('#input_2_37').val($('#input_2_4_1').val());
            $('#input_2_38').val($('#input_2_4_3').val());
            $('#input_2_39').val($('#input_2_4_5').val());
            $('#input_2_40').val($('#input_2_33').val());
            $('#input_2_41').val($('#input_2_34').val());
        };
    });
});
```

Erase code:

```
jQuery(document).erase(function($) {
    $('input#choice_2_20_1').click(function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#input_35').val("");
            $('#input_36').val("");
            $('#input_37').val("");
            $('#input_38').val("");
            $('#input_39').val("");
            $('#input_40').val("");
            $('#input_41').val("");
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: For us to help you with this you'll need to show the [mcve] HTML as well.

Comment: @DavidThomas thanks for a quick reply. This is being used on Wordpress, so I believe it's not that easy to provide a simple HTML and people around here do not prefer URL's. However, the form is here: http://marianrehak.cz/ikem/ The field stejne-jmeno is were the Jméno fields gets copied and the one that needs to gets deleted after click on the second checkbox.Is this of any hep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see, on the copy code, you have id's like this

```
#input_2_35
#input_2_36
```

and on the erase, you have different id's

```
#input_35
#input_36
```

just change your erase code to fit the id's

```
jQuery(document).erase(function($) {
    $('input#choice_2_20_1').click(function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#input_2_35').val("");
            $('#input_2_36').val("");
            $('#input_2_37').val("");
            $('#input_2_38').val("");
            $('#input_2_39').val("");
            $('#input_2_40').val("");
            $('#input_2_41').val("");
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I have not noticed the different id's

Answer (score 1):

Move the content of the erase function into the ready function and then it should works.

Look at the [example here](https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/6042/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#check').click(function() {
       if($(this).is(':checked')) {
          $('#text2').val($('#text').val());
        };
    });

   $('#check2').click(function() {
       if($(this).is(':checked')) {
           $('#text2').val('');
       };
   });
});
```